# Process for updating custom package within an application

Tags: git, laravel, package

In my Laravel5 app I created a new package, and have it working as needed. Went through the steps to get it up and running on Packagist and have it pulling through my require in composer.json which is working great.

I guess my struggle then comes from making new updates to this package, since I'm unable to update the package using git within my app (also maintained by git) do I need to create a second app that I would use to modify this package? I'm sure there's a much easier way I'm overlooking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pull your package with composer so the `.git` folder of the package is removed as it isn't needed.

If you want to develop your package inside another project I do this simple process:

My package is for example tzookb/tbmsg
I go to folder

```
/vendor/tzookb
```

I remove the folder tbmsg
Now I clone my package tbmsg in to the folder 
It will arrive with all the .git files
Now you can develop
Commit and push
Finish